# virtualenv module name conflict

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a very basic virtualenv setup on OSX with two packages, py3dns, and dnspython.  Both packages have a dns module(actually one is DNS, the other dns, but on OSX they are the same), and these modules both have files named opcode.py.

Virtual env is installing both of these modules into lib/python3.5/site-packages/, and not into lib/python3.5/site-packages/#{package}, therefore these opcode.py files are overwriting each other.

Is this a bug(feature?) of virtualenv?  Is there some way around this?  Unfortunately I dont have the option of using only one of these dns packages, as they are both indirectly imported via other packages that I need to use in my project.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify different target path https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-t

You can install second package like this:

```
pip3 install dnspython --target /Users/green/dns
```

and then create file dns.pth in site-packages with path to package:

```
/Users/green/dns
```

and in your code:

```
from dns.opcode import from_text
from DNS.Opcode import opcodemap

print("ok")
```

Comment: I'm actually using tox, which is on top of virtualenv.  This would work if I could configure tox to pass it this argument, but I'm not certain I can.

Comment: I'm not familiar with tox, sorry